# example of soap in node.js with execution procedure?

Tags: node.js, soap

i am looking for a complete example of easySoap and node.js ? And also how to run it in node.js. I have easySoap module installed in my node.js software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see a full example on Github 
https://github.com/moszeed/easysoap ...

Hope it helps ...